# backbone.js upon deleting model from db delete it from view

Tags: backbone.js, view, destroy

I have a problem - I've created a delete link for every model & it deleted from db... but I didn't manage to correctly set up a callback on delete event for it's correct visual display.

```
class Notes.Views.ArticlesIndex extends Backbone.View.     
  render: ->  
    $(@el).html(@template())  
    @collection.each(@appendEntry)  
    this  

  appendEntry: (article)->  
    view = new Notes.Views.Article(model: article)  
    $('ul#article_list').append(view.render().el)  


class Notes.Views.Article extends Backbone.View   
  template: JST['articles/menu']    
  events:  
    'click a.delete': 'deleteEntry'   
  initialize: ->  
    # putting @model.on('destroy',@render,this) didn't help    
  deleteEntry: (event)->  
    event.preventDefault()  
    @model.destroy()
```

**UPDATE !**
as addition to @nEEbz answer, adding `@model.on('destroy',@remove,this)` callback also helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
deleteEntry: (event)->
    event.preventDefault()
    @model.destroy()
    @$el.remove()
```

Comment: Edited my question, added one more method of solving this problem